# Can .sortable apply to dynamically added objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please explain that whether `.sortable` can apply to future jQuery objects that will be dynamically added, which means it doesn't exist in the **current** DOM , just like the deprecated `.live` function? Thanks.

Comment: You mean does it gratuitously use the root-level `document` to delegate for all and any now and future events to make lazy programmers lives easier instead of using a scope closer and logically more consistent with the purpose of the event? Hmm. I don't know. Hope not, or it'll get yanked like `$.live()` did.

Comment: If only there were some way to find out...

Comment: Look at the `refresh` method of `sortable`: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh You need to call it after you add dynamic items to sortable.

Comment: Hi , All, Please let me spend more time to check api and do some experiments. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: No.

Take note of the following: [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7, and is removed in jQuery 1.9. This functionality has been moved/replaced by the [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. This method can only detect **event handlers**, like `click` etc. `.sortable` isn't an event handler, so this wouldn't work.

The only thing you can do, is to call the [`.sortable`](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) method (from jQuery UI) after you created the elements.

Comment: Ok, I got it ,that means the elements I want to be `sortable` must exist in advance. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answering in 2018, you can achieve this by just initializing the sortable after adding the new element to dom. In my case, I'm working on a form layout plugin where one would add columns and fields and needs to sort them. So after creating (dynamically) a new column, I re-apply the code which I've turned into a function:

```
function g2f_reload_sortable() {
    // reapply sortable to new items
    $('#g2f-form-fields div[class^="col"]').sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        connectWith: "#g2f-form-fields div[class^='col']",
        handle: ".g2f-field-move"
    });
    $('#g2f-form-fields div[class^="col"]').disableSelection();
}
```

This works for me.